# Is CakePhp adding timestamp to my javascript files requested by ajax?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using Pjax to fetch pages on my cakePhp website. I am getting an error due to the javascript being fetch again because it see's it as a new file due the .js?_=timestamp being added to it.

main.min.js?_=1425763395728

If a page is being requested by ajax does cakePhp add this? I cant think of any other reason why it is getting returned with a timestamp.

I am using CakePhp 2.5

UPDATE:

The issue was jQuery and this helped to remove the timestamp.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  if ( options.dataType == 'script' || originalOptions.dataType == 'script' ) {
      options.cache = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your `Asset.timestamp` config var is set to `'force'`or `true`. Setting this to `false` will remove the query string timestamp from your assets. This is documented in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html

The only downside is that browsers may cache your JavaScript and CSS files and might use out-of-date assets if you update them.

*Edit*

Since this didn't help the OP it's likely that the timestamp is not being added by CakePHP. I would look at 3rd party libraries your are using, specifically in JavaScript but potentially in any CakePHP plugins or PHP libraries to see if they may be adding the query string.

*End Edit*

Comment: Yes I had looked at that. This is a fresh install of cakephp with no real configuration. This setting is commented out and set to false by default.

Comment: just in case it was Asset.timestamp I have uncomment it out and set to false and I have also set debug level to 0. I still get the timestamp returned on the .js file.

Comment: I Added some more details as to what to check when my first suggestion didn't work. Are you seeing these in the rendered HTML or are they only appearing in the XHRs your JAvaScript library is making?

Comment: I am only seeing this in the XHR. I have a clean CakePHP and I am only running jQuery and the Pjax plugin. It is definitely not the plugin so I am going to look at jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Although OP posted the solution, the final check-marked answer did not offer a solution - the issue is not related to `Asset.timestamp` in CakePHP, but rather the default jquery ajax behavior, which (as OP already stated) can be adjusted by placing following code snippet before the ajax requests are called:

```
//Cache Ajax request script files
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  if ( options.dataType == 'script' || originalOptions.dataType == 'script' ) {
      options.cache = true;
  }
});
```

OR

```
//Cache all Ajax request related files
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
      options.cache = true;
});
```

Took me a while to figure this post, so hopefully this note helps others find the answer quicker. Thanks Keith!